# Bootstrap 4 fluid Flex row with 2 responsive columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

My goal is to make [this area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04t7H.png) as responsive as possible. Looks great on extra large viewports, however when we start shrinking down, example: [viewport at ~930px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4uXd.png) I cannot keep the photo lined up perfectly as in the first screenshot.

I've attempted making the photo area a `background-size: cover`, however, that solution just cuts off the edges of the picture as we get to a smaller viewport (and that is not an option).

The second issue is on a mobile viewport: these 2 blocks need to stack. Pretty sure I can figure that part out after the first problem has been solved, though.

```
<section class="card-group">
     <div class="card">
          <img src="..." class="img-fluid">
     </div>
     <div class="card card-vcenter">
          <div class="card-block">.....</div>
     </div>
</section>

.card-vcenter{
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use proper bootstrap responsive classes.  Your problem may be found in the CSS styles for those .card, .card-group classes.

You should code as such:

```
 <section class="card-group">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">    
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="..." class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="cold-md-6">
        <div class="card-block">.....</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Add a new `<div class="row">` and your two col-md-6 for each of your cards, then close the container and section

Your CSS:

```
section.card-group img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
section.card-group .col-md-6 {
  /*insert background, font, padding, margin styles*/
}
section.card-group .card-block {
  /*insert background, font, padding, margin styles*/
}
```

With bootstrap's already responsive working classes, you can ditch your "card" classes and wont have to bother with how your content will line up.  Read up on your bootstrap documentation! :)

Comment: +1 you are absolutely correct. I should have been thinking more basic rather than trying to overload the code with the new BS4 components where they do not belong.

Comment: It's easy to overdo/overthink your code!  But if you work with your framework instead of against it you'll eliminate most responsiveness issues